# Find records with same string with extra character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, full-text-search, string-searching

OK, so I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 database table called `owner` with around 90,000 records with owner information, another called `vehicle` with vehicle information

```
Owner_Name                   owner_id       V_name     owner_id    exempt
-------------------------------------       ------------------------------
JACOB JAMISON & JESSICA           35        Civic            35        H3
JACOB JAMISON M & JESSICA B       39        Accord           39        H3 
BLACKSON BARRINGTON               56        Bugatti          56        H6
BLACKSON BARRINGTON H             98        SSC              98        H7
BRUSTER MICHAEL                   107       Corvette         107       H9
```

I'm trying to find all records that have more than one exemption on a vehicle 
   ( `H0` means no exemption). This code below has worked well, **as long as the name is exactly the same**. However, if there's a variation, such as an extra letter or if it's entered backwards, then it won't return those records. I've looked at things like `SOUNDEX`, but this wouldn't work in my scenario.

```
SELECT Owner_name
     , COUNT(Owner_name) AS 'xNameAppears'
     , COUNT(v.exempt) AS 'ExemptionCount' 
FROM owner o
INNER JOIN vehicle V ON V.owner_id = o.owner_id
WHERE v.exempt <> 'H0'
GROUP BY O.owner_name
HAVING COUNT(v.exempt) > 1
```

Is there a solution that would allow me to return records like so, not knowing which `owner_name`'s may be similar? Basically trying to get the server to search through the `owner_name` column and if there's a similarity such as 
`JACOB JAMISON & JESSICA` and `JACOB JAMISON M & JESSICA B` then it'll return those records like so:

```
Owner_Name                      xNameAppears      ExemptCount
-------------------------------------------------------------      
JACOB JAMISON & JESSICA           2                         2
JACOB JAMISON M & JESSICA B       2                         2
BLACKSON BARRINGTON               2                         2
BLACKSON BARRINGTON H             2                         2
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sure `SOUNDEX` is suitable? The following all return the same value `SOUNDEX('JACOB JAMISON & JESSICA '), SOUNDEX('Jacob Zuma'), SOUNDEX('Jacob Willekens'), SOUNDEX('Jacob S. Coxey, Sr.'), SOUNDEX('Juegief zzzzzzzzzzzz')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [SOUNDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function can be applied to a column as well.

But since

> there's thousands like that

I wouldn't suggest just writing a query to join on a function to do that.

This will likely not perform very well on larger tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.vehicle AS v
JOIN dbo.vehicle AS v2
ON SOUNDEX(v2.Owner_Name) = SOUNDEX(v.Owner_Name)
AND v2.Owner_Name <> v.Owner_Name;
```

I'd rather do something that will make finding this easier in the long-term.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.vehicle (Owner_Name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT dbo.vehicle ( Owner_Name )
SELECT *
FROM (  
VALUES            
('JACOB JAMISON & JESSICA'),
('JACOB JAMISON M & JESSICA B'),
('BLACKSON BARRINGTON'),          
('BLACKSON BARRINGTON H'),        
('BRUSTER MICHAEL')
) AS x (Owner_Name);
```

I'm going to add a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) based on the function, and then add an index to aid my query.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.vehicle ADD Owner_Soundex AS SOUNDEX(Owner_Name);

CREATE INDEX ix_whatever ON dbo.vehicle (Owner_Soundex, Owner_Name);
```

Validate that everything looks good...

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.vehicle AS v
```

Use a query like this to find imprecise matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.vehicle AS v
JOIN dbo.vehicle AS v2
ON v2.Owner_Soundex = v.Owner_Soundex
AND v2.Owner_Name <> v.Owner_Name;
```

Comment: You sir, are the man. I didn't think to use `SOUNDEX` in that manner. This works very well! Indeed that second way is more efficient performance wise. Thank you.

Comment: @user1227080 happy to help!